# List-items automatically update while they're in an Object and they shouldn't

Tags: c#

I started to make a football game app in C#. I should make 15 Matchdays. Every matchday has a number, date and two lists with teams in it. In every MatchDay the teams with the same index in the lists play against eachother. (TeamList1[0] plays against TeamList2[0], ...). I make 15 matchdays with a for loop and switch the teams in the lists with the SwitchTeams() method. First i make a matchday-object with the two lists in it, then I put this matchday in a MatchDayList  and then i change the lists and make the next matchday object. But when i switch the teams in the list in the normal code, the list in my MatchDay object changes as well. 
I don't know how this is possible and how to make the normal lists change and the lists that are in the MatchDay object remain the same. Does anyone have a solution for this? Thank you

```
//variables
List<Team> teamList1 = new List<Team>();
List<Team> teamList2 = new List<Team>();
List<MatchDay> matchDayList = new List<MatchDay>();

//Making the 15 Matchdays
private void ComposeGamesMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 7, 31);
            while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                date = date.AddDays(-1);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
                List<Team> helpList1 = teamList1;
                List<Team> helpList2 = teamList2;
                MatchDay helpMatchDay = new MatchDay(i, helpList1, helpList2, date);
                matchDayList.Add(helpMatchDay);
                SwitchTeams();
                date = date.AddDays(7);
            }        
        }

// Switching teams in original lists
 private void SwitchTeams()
        {
            teamList2.Insert(0, teamList1[1]);
            teamList1.RemoveAt(1);
            teamList1.Add(teamList2[8]);
            teamList2.RemoveAt(8);
        }

//Matchday class
public class MatchDay
    {
        private int DayNumber;
        private List<Team> TeamsList1;
        private List<Team> TeamsList2;
        private List<int> ScoresList1;
        private List<int> ScoresList2;
        private DateTime Date;

public MatchDay(int dayNumber, List<Team> teamsList1, List<Team> teamsList2, DateTime date)
        {
            DayNumber = dayNumber;
            TeamsList1 = teamsList1;
            TeamsList2 = teamsList2;
            Date = date;
        }
    }
```

I expect the List in TeamList1 and TeamList2 in the Matchday Class not the change after the SwitchTeams() method. Only the TeamList1 and TeamList2 that are variables should change and put in the new Matchday Object and also not change ofcourse.

Comment: `helpList1` is the same thing as `teamList1` so when you pass them to MatchDay the list there is the same thing too, so of course changing one changes them all.

Comment: Are you aware that assigning things like `List<Team> helpList1 = teamList1` is just copying the reference and not the items? So if you delete one from the `helpList1` you also lose it in the `teamList1`..

Comment: to piggy back on @JeroenvanLangen you can google 'deep copy' to see how to make a clone of a list

Comment: @Kevin lol, a `myList.ToList()` will do just fine, if the items doesn't need to be cloned ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's the same list.  In your program you have exactly two lists of teams:

```
List<Team> teamList1 = new List<Team>();
List<Team> teamList2 = new List<Team>();
```

You never create any more.  When you use them to construct your `MatchDay` object:

```
new MatchDay(i, helpList1, helpList2, date)
```

That object now has a *reference* to each list.  Any changes made to a list will be visible by all references to that list.  They haven't been copied.

You can create new lists with the `.ToList()` extension method.  For example:

```
new MatchDay(i, helpList1.ToList(), helpList2.ToList(), date)
```

This would create new *lists*, but they would of course still have references to the same *objects*.  So you can modify one list, and it won't modify the other one.  But if you modify a property on one of the objects in that list it *will* modify the object in the original list as well, and all for the same reason as the original problem you described.

In general, assigning a reference-type object (anything other than primitive types like `int`, `bool`, `double`, etc.) to a variable does not create a copy of that object, it just sets that variable as a reference to that same object.

Comment: Thanks. So if I use the ToList() method it should work?

Comment: @MarcianoAntonacci: That would create a new list, containing the same objects as the original list.  You could also explicitly create a new list and populate it with the same objects, if you want it to be more obvious when reading the code.